# Jwplayer is working on google chrome but not working in IE version 11

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser, jwplayer

Jwplayer is working on google chrome but not working in IE version 11.

```
 Here is my code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
    <title>Player Widget</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/D0JWLonA.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--<script data-main="playercomponent.playerwidget" src="script/require.js"></script>-->
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player-widget-container" style="float:left;"></div>
    <div>Text to display in full screen mode at bottom</div>
</body>
<script>
    //$(document).ready(function () {
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("player-widget-container");
    playerInstance.setup({
        file: "http://182.70.125.99/edge360/videos/cam1/fast.mp4",
        title: "title",
        width: 500,
        height: 300,
        autostart: false,
        controls: true,
        repeat: true,
    });
    //})
</script>
</html>
```

also "Text to display in full screen mode at bottom" should be visible in full screen mode below the player.

Comment: what is the error you are getting in console, have you tried debugging it ?

Comment: Yes, i have tried to debugging it and get error: Unable to get property 'jwplayer.volume' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when viewing file in *offline* (from `file://` protocol).

I had unminified my jwplayer.js code and than error occurred on line *3088*.

All I had to do was replace this code:

```
var e = j[c(d)];
return e && (a[d] = b.serialize(e)), a
```

to

```
if (typeof j !== 'undefined') {
    var e = j[c(d)];
    return e && (a[d] = b.serialize(e)), a
} else {
    return false, a
}
```

*or in minfied version*

line 3:12.436 (search for `j[c(d)]`)

`if(typeof(j)!=='undefined'){var e=j[c(d)];return e&&(a[d]=b.serialize(e)),a}else{return false,a}`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I just experienced this issue in JWPlayer and I couldn't find any decent technote for it, so I thought I'd write it up here...

I had a user who received the error, `Unable to get property 'jwplayer.volume' of undefined or null reference` when using JWPlayer (7.9.3) in IE 11 with Windows 7 (over http).

It turns out that she had *DOM Storage* disabled in IE 11. And after a bit of research, I figured out that JWPlayer throws this script error when localStorage is unavailable. The problem was resolved after she changed her IE settings under **Internet Options** -> **Advanced** tab -> **Security** section. Make sure **Enable DOM Storage** is CHECKED.

Ideally JWPlayer will fix this issue in future versions.

Comment: In my case Enable DOM Storage is checked and it does not work. :'(